# How to sort 2 different lists synchronously in R?

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have the lists

```
examplevar1 = [x1, x3, x2]
examplenum1 = [0.1, -5, 2.4]
```

I need to sort both synchronously so that the result is

```
examplevar1 = [x1, x2, x3]
examplenum1 = [01, 2.4, -5]
```

I am reading about ```sort()`` function while typing this out, but it doesn't seem like it will work for this scenario.

I will be trying out stuff as well while I wait for an answer here.

Thanks!

Edit: Adding code where it will be used on

```
fixAllwMatrix = function(smbls,numbs,matrixx){
  
  count = 0
  for (itema in smbls) {
    count = count + 1
    if(identical(toString(itema),"+")){
      smbls = smbls[(0-count)]
      count = count - 1
      
    }
    if(identical(toString(itema),"*")){
      smbls = smbls[(0-count)]
      count = count - 1
    }
    if(identical(toString(itema),"-")){
      numbs[count] = numbs[count] * -1
      smbls = smbls[(0-count)]
      count = count - 1
    }
    
  }
  print(smbls)
  for (a in smbls) {
    print(typeof(a))
    a = toString(a)
    print(typeof(a))
  }
  df = data.frame(var1 = smbls, num1 = numbs)
  df1 = df[order(as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', smbls))), ]
  print(df1)
```

where:
`smbls` is the variables (the smbls `for` loop is for removing + - and * items in the list. And during that `for` loop, the list items are of type "symbols"
`numbs` is the numbers that are given
the last `for` loop is to turn the smbls items to string
then in the last pert, the dataframe part, I get the error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  object 'x1' not found
```

Is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can put both the vectors in a dataframe and use `gtools::mixedorder` :

```
examplevar1 = c('x1', 'x3', 'x2')
examplenum1 = c(0.1, -5, 2.4)
df <- data.frame(var1 = examplevar1, num1 = examplenum1)
df1 <- df[gtools::mixedorder(df$var1), ]

#  var1 num1
#1   x1  0.1
#3   x2  2.4
#2   x3 -5.0
```

---

Also in base R :

```
df1 <- df[order(as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', examplevar1))), ]
```

Comment: Sorry for replying 5 hours later. I was busy with something. I tried your answer, both the ```gtools``` and the one for base R, but I keep getting the error ```Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  object 'x1' not found```. Is there a problem in it that I need to fix?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example for me to test this? Currently the data is not reproducible.

Comment: I have added the function I used

Comment: We need data more than the code. Please add output of `dput(df)` in your question. Or you can also add `dput(smbls)` and `dput(numbs)`.